# Fibonacci sequence results in infinity, then NaN

Tags: javascript, html, linear-algebra

I was playing around with writing a javascript Fibonacci sequence, as I had never tried to do so, came up with an easy iterative formula to calculate it. Then I decided to test run it by doing 10000 iterations to see the results. to my surprise, it worked until the 1476th iteration, then broke. 1477 and 1478 both gave the result "Infinity". I have tried different browsers, changing the methods for display, but ended up with the same results.

1475i - 1.3069892237633983e+308
1476i - Infinity
1477i - Infinity
1478i - NaN

Code used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script>
function fibonacci(){
var x = 1;
var y = 0;
  for(i=0;i<1478;i++){
    var box = document.createElement('div');
    box.setAttribute('id','box'+i);
    document.body.appendChild(box);
    document.getElementById('box'+i).innerHTML = [i] + 'i - ' + x;
        x = x + y;
    y = x - y;
  }
}
</script></head><body onLoad="fibonacci();"><div id="output"></div></body></html>
```

I am not sure if then function broke at a certain point, or what I may have failed to take into accountof in the sequence. And yes, I realize that I skipped the first integer, but that shouldn't affect the function.

Comment: JavaScript uses 64bit integers. Meaning, JavaScript can only hold a value as large as 2^64 - 1. However, I am not 100% sure if this is the issue you are facing.

Comment: This was done without looking at any other samples, which upon doing so, it looks as though most are using much more complex ways of obtaining the same result. I think it is a matter of the number being too large. My thanks.

Comment: @JustinWood That's not true. JavaScript uses 64bit *floating point* with a 52-bit mantissa. One way to see this is to observe that the first integer that JavaScript cannot hold as a number is 2^53+1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1477th Fibonacci number is too big to be represented by Javascript. The "overflow" causes your number to become `Infinity`.

`Infinity - 1476thFibonacciNumber` is still `Infinity` in the following `y` calculation.

Then on the next iteration you have `Infinity - Infinity` which is `NaN` in `JavaScript`. From that point, it's `NaN` all the way to the end.

Answer (score 3):

The largest value Javascript can handle is 1.7976931348623157e+308. If your code generates anything larger than this it will break.

Answer (score 1):

For large values of N, the Fibonacci series can be approximated by

```
F(N) = math.pow(phi, N) / math.sqrt(5)
```

(ref: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html#fibround )

Where `phi` is the golden ratio: (sqrt(5)+1)/2

You can now figure out what the largest Fibonacci number is that you can calculate with the following:

```
phi = (math.sqrt(5)+1)/2
fibMax = math.floor(log(1.79769)/log(phi) +  math.log(math.sqrt(5)))
```

And the answer from the above is... `1475` - which is the largest number you were able to compute without overflow.

Bottom line - once your calculation overflows, it will continue to do so. `Infinity + anything = Infinity`, and interestingly `Infinity - anything = still infinity`. And `infinity + infinity = NaN`. So even if you subtracted the last number off again, you would not get back to a "real" number. That's just how overflow is treated.

Comment: This is way above my head, not a mathematician, but definitely very interesting. My thanks for the info and link.

Comment: No worries - you are computing the Fibonacci series "by hand" which puts you in the "more mathematician than not" category for sure. I was just showing that the place where your calculation keeled over was "just as expected" - namely where the approximation of F(N) for large N becomes bigger than the biggest number you can represent in Javascript. So all is well with the world. Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

On the subject of the Fibonacci sequence in JavaScript. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)has a good example using generators:

```
// Declare generator
function* fibonacci() {
    let n0;
    let n1 = 0
    let n2 = 1
    while (true) {
        n0 = n1
        n1 = n2
        n2 = n0 + n1
        yield n0
    }
}

// Create generator
var y = fibonacci()

// Print them out
for (let x = 0; x < 1477; x++) {
    console.log(x + 1, " ", y.next().value)
}
```